# Does Android keep the view object hierarchy in memory?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, memory, android-memory

When I create a button:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   LinearLayout layout = …;

   Button btn = new Button(this);
   btn.setText("My Button");

   layout.addView(btn);
}
```

If I don't keep a strong reference to the `btn`, does Android keep the `btn` instance alive?

For example, does `layout.getChildView(0)` return the exact instance (`btn`)? or does Android create and return a new instance of `Button` and return it?

I'm not talking about subclassing, (e.g. `class MyButton extends Button`) which I think it's obvious it must be kept in memory, I am only asking about built-in view classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewGroup stores strong references on its children in an array. If you take a look into ViewGroup sources you find following field:

```
private View[] mChildren;
```

And when you call `getChildAt` you get an instance from this array:

```
public View getChildAt(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= mChildrenCount) {
        return null;
    }
    return mChildren[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any view group when you are adding any child view at a time it will not create new instance.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: It will not create new instance, assume like you have added one textview to any view group and then if you updating textview, it will reflect. So it means it's reference , not creating new instance.

Comment: But if textview which you have added is not reflected their change then we can say it is creating new instance.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was asking.

Comment: What are asking for ?? That I can't understand sorry,